Interpreting "Log Probability" in Optimization/Statistics/Machine Learning
It seems like in machine learning we work with log probabilities a lot, like, minimize, maximize log probability. This makes sense from a numerical perspective since adding is easier than multiplying but I am also wondering if there is a fundamental meaning behind "log probability."
For instance, log probability is used a lot in information theory. How can we interpret log probability?
Maybe my attempt is that machine learning attempts to fit the data distribution, and maximizing the log probability is a way of encoding the 'information' in that distribution. Is this a possible interpretation?

For an event with probability $p$, $-\log p$ is interpreted as the information associated with the event. Didn’t that show up in your reading?

Consider converting a sum of log probabilities to a product of probabilities. Since probabilities are less than one, the product quickly vanishes so products
are impractical for large data sets.

Ok @A rural reader, can you interpret this in the context of optimization then?

Maximising the log probability  has the same effect as maximising the probability, and is often simpler mechanically.  But it would be wrong to say that the mode of a distribution encodes the information in that distribution, except in some very special cases.

The earliest motivation is likely via statistical mechanics. In 1877, Boltzmann was looking to describe the entropy of a body in its own given macrostate of thermodynamic equilibrium as a function of the number of microstates consistent with the equilibrium. See this summary on Wikipedia:

In Boltzmann’s 1877 paper, he clarifies molecular state counting to determine the state distribution number introducing the logarithm to simplify the equation.


Boltzmann writes: “The first task is to determine the permutation number, previously designated by  , for any state distribution. Denoting by J the sum of the permutations  for all possible state distributions, the quotient  /J is the state distribution’s probability, henceforth denoted by W. We would first like to calculate the permutations  for the state distribution characterized by $w_0$ molecules with kinetic energy 0, $w_1$ molecules with kinetic energy ϵ, etc. …


“The most likely state distribution will be for those $w_0, w_1 …$ values for which  is a maximum or since the numerator is a constant, for which the denominator is a minimum. The values $w_0, w_1$ must simultaneously satisfy the two constraints (1) and (2). Since the denominator of  is a product, it is easiest to determine the minimum of its logarithm, …”


Therefore, by making the denominator small, he maximizes the number of states. So to simplify the product of the factorials, he uses their natural logarithm to add them. This is the reason for the natural logarithm in Boltzmann’s entropy formula.

Harry Nyquist and Ralph Hartley would later apply this idea to information theory in the 20s, and Claude Shannon popularizes it in his seminal 1948 paper. That paper, along with much of Shannon's other work in the 50s, pretty much kickstarts the fields of artificial intelligence and machine learning.

Thanks for the awesome answer. But it seems like they're just using the log as a numerical trick/to turn adds into sums. Does this provide an interpretation of "log probability"?
